# Rails sql inner join: How can I exclude all rows on same id when only 1 row matching the excluded condition?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join

Let’s say I have an inner join between table Animals and table AnimalType showing records like below:

```
╔════════════╦══════════════╗
║ animal_id  ║ animal_type  ║
╠════════════╬══════════════╣
║          1 ║ land         ║
║          1 ║ 4 legs       ║
║          1 ║ below 10 kgs ║
╚════════════╩══════════════╝
```

I want to to exclude all 3 rows because animal Id 1 is ‘below 10 kgs’

I know if try smt like “where animal_type != ‘below 10 kgs’” then only 1 row be excluded from the inner join records.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Show the query that you are using.

Comment: I cannot understand the table structure from what you provided.

Comment: I just edited for better information

Answer (score 4):

You could use exists logic here:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
                  WHERE t2.animal_id = t1.animal_id AND
                        t2.animal_type = 'below 10 kgs');
```

### Demo

I assume just a single table here, though if you really have a join between two tables, the exact same approach should work with slight modification.